# export/convert emails (.eml files) to plain text

Tags: email, text

So I have an ancient archive of emails and I want to combine them into one big happy text file, can that be done?  I notice when I view an email and cut and paste the content I get exactly what I want -- all the formatting is gone and I have a readable text file, all the meta data is gone along with all the HTML stuff.  I've looked at 'html2text' but it leaves all the tags in, whereas I'd have thought it would strip them out.  I could view, cut and paste, but that would take a long time.

BTW I use Thunderbird if that matters.  I don't think I can do this within the program, it's going to be some command line utility I expect.

Comment: Does "I have an archive of emails" and "I use Thunderbird" mean that this archive is simply a folder in Thunderbird? If that's the case, congratulations, your archive already *is* one large text file (an mbox file, to be specific).

Comment: Nope, they're separate .eml files that go way back to DOS.  I can view them with Tbird but they are individual.  A possible line of attack is to somehow import them to Tbird but then I'd like to convert them to great big text files.

Comment: that would be pretty important to know, would you mind adding that info to your question?

Comment: by the way, your eml files are also just text files; and if you just concatenate them, one after the other into one gigantic file, that's exactly the mbox format that thunderbird uses for archives :D

Comment: 'just text' and tons of meta data and HTML tags.  I just want the bodies.

Comment: got you! hm; relative easy to script in Python and perl, I'm sure there's indeed CLI tools for this

Comment: Yeah I'm betting there is.  Someone here will know.

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392361/how-to-read-eml-file-in-python) might help

Comment: If I was a python user I'd try it.  Wonder if there's similar in zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scripted solution using:

- `formail` (comes with `procmail`) to convert the emails to mailbox format
- `mutt` to decode the mime stuff
- `elinks` to convert HTML to text for those emails that don't have a `text/plain` alternative
- `zsh` to orchestrate the lot and find the `eml` files in the current working directory and below.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
MAILCAPS==(
print 'text/html; /usr/bin/elinks -force-html -dump %s; copiousoutput'
) mutt -F =(<<'EOF'
set pipe_decode
set pipe_split
alternative_order text/plain text
unset wait_key
auto_view text/html
push "<tag-pattern>~A<enter><tag-prefix-cond><pipe-message>formail>>out.mbox<enter><exit>"
EOF
) -f =(for f (**/*.eml(n.)) formail < $f) > /dev/null
```

The text is appended to the `out.mbox` file. That file can still be opened as a mail folder by most mail user agents (don't know about Thunderbird) and should be plain text with most headers weeded.

If you don't care about the file being in mailbox format, you can replace the `formail>>out.mbox` with `cat>>out.txt`, and if you don't care about headers, with `sed '1,/^$/d'>>out.txt`.

Check the `elinks` man page for how to tune the HTML to text rendering if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird has an attachment that does it: [ImportExportTools](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/).  First you use it to import the loose .eml files, then you export them to a single text file.  Works well.